# How to change the default project view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I launch Android Studio, the view is set on `Project`:

[image]

What I would like to have is the view being set on `Android`:

[image]

Any way to modify this behavior persistently? I've searched in the `Settings` but did not find anything related to this.

Comment: Have you tried restoring the default layout of the android studio?

Comment: @Yousaf no because I've many other settings I would rather not lose

Comment: which android studio version are you using?

Comment: @Yousaf Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Normally android studio opens each project in android view by default. If that's not the case in your android studio, i don't see any other workaround other than to restore default layout. I hope someone else knows a solution to this problem that can prevent you from having to restore default layout..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Help -> Edit Custom Properties
`studio.projectview=true`

Comment: I assume this is only possible in Studio, not other jetbrains ide with Android plugin?

Comment: @cricket_007 up to you to test, but I would assume so as well

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore :-/ Here are all the flags available: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue. The issue was due to Zip folder.
When it extracted zip folder it created Project name folder inside a folder.
So when I imported that it was not giving Android menu.

[image]

So issue resolver when I deleted the outer folder with similar name.